# Joining to tables/columns specified by query results

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Maybe I am not searching the correct terms, because I found no other questions/answers re: this.

Is it possible to join to a table/column designated in the results from a query? I have a query with objects that are designated in other tables, and I can create a table of all tables/columns.

**Example**

*Table_1*

```
        Col1        Col2        Col3
        999         HTML        001
        998         HTML        002
        997         CSS         001
        996         CSS         002
        995         CSS         003
        994         C#          001
```

*Table_2 - Table of Tables/Columns*

```
        Col1        Col2        Col3
        HTML        T_HTML      C_HTML_ID
        CSS         T_CSS       C_CSS_ID
        C#          T_C#        C_C#_ID
```

*Table_3 - T_HTML (but could be T_CSS, T_C#, etc.)*

```
        C_HTML_ID        Col2
        001              blah
        002              blah
        003              blah
```

Is it then possible to somehow do something like this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_1
    JOIN table_2
        ON table_2.Col1 = table_1.Col2
    JOIN <<table_2.Col2>>
        ON <<table_2.Col2>>.<<Col3>> = table_1.Col3
```

Comment: you can't join columns. you join tables. what is you expected result on doing that?

Comment: no it is not possible this way. You should think about to redesign your database model. this looks like a bad design

Comment: Unfortunately, I am just a report monkey.

Answer (score 0):

***Join doesn't work that way.***
Please see how join works in this https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for better understanding.

Comment: I know how joins work. I think what I may need to be looking for keyword wise is Dynamic SQL: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can join the table_1 and table_3 direct.

```
select * 
from tab1 t1
join tab3 t2 on t1.Col3 = t2.C_HTML_ID
where t1.Col2 = 'HTML';
```